# Can you kill two players with a single shot in Urban Terror?

Tags: urban-terror

Phrased another way, does any kind of round penetrate players e.g. those fired by the PSG-1 or the SR8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. Maybe it can be the case with [SPAS-12](http://urt.taggedzi.com/spas.php) (due to its ammo nature).

However, obviously, the [HE grenade](http://urt.taggedzi.com/he.php) (and [HK-69](http://urt.taggedzi.com/hk69.php)) allows you to kill more than one player with one grenade ...

Comment: One green tick for you as the only answer in quite some time :) Good point on the spas too.

Comment: Well, notice the SPAS is only a guess. But for the nades, i'm sure, as regularly see multiples "monorailkitty was reduced to a (i don't remember the word) by Riduidel grenade".